# How to make two inputfields that show the same data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have one input field that needs to pop up in another place when the user changes a tab and presses a button,
but I figured tossing the div around would be too much hassle,
so is it instead possible to make two input fields but have them display the same input entered by the user?

Or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Of course, make sure it is on [DOM `.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

```
$('#input1').blur(function() {
    $('#input2').val( this.value );
});
```

- [Use `.blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) to run the code when the user leaves the `input1`.
- [Use `.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set the value of `input2` to the `this.value` of `input1`.

If you need to work the reverse direction as well, just assign another handler, reversing the inputs.

```
$('#input2').blur(function() {
    $('#input1').val( this.value );
});
```

---

**EDIT:** To deal with multiple inputs, give them all the same class, then use paired IDs.

Like this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/m3q4V/

```
<!-- In tab 1 -->
<input type="text" class="someClass" id="address_1" />
<input type="text" class="someClass" id="city_1" />
<input type="text" class="someClass" id="zip_1" />

<!-- In tab 2 -->
<input type="text" class="someClass" id="address_2" />
<input type="text" class="someClass" id="city_2" />
<input type="text" class="someClass" id="zip_2" />
```

js:

```
$('.someClass').blur(function() {
    var parts = this.id.split('_'); // separate into parts, like 'address' and '2'
    var num = (parts[1] == 2) ? 1 : 2;  // invert the number between 1 and 2
      // build the selector with 'address' + '_' + '1'
    $('#' + parts[0] + '_' + num).val( this.value );
});
```

Comment: +1, gets my vote because it sounds like both inputs aren't going to be visible at the same time, making this the simplest approach.

Comment: That's fair, but assume the number of input fields increase, is there a way to contain the code to not need 6 lines per field? It'll blow a fair bit out of proportion after a while

Comment: @Meke - Sure, we could change it to work for multiple input pairs. Depends on your markup. I'd give them all the same class, then give them IDs that are paired, like `address_tab_1 address_tab_2`. Then we can easily get the numeric portion of the ID, and use it to select its pair. I'll update in a minute.

Comment: @Meke - You're welcome. Glad it worked for you. I just noticed that I had forgotten the `var` keyword for the `num` variable. Fixed. Those are important. :o)

Answer (score 1):

### [See Working Example](http://jsbin.com/uyilo3)

---

If you want to happen that when first text box loses focus, you need to use [`blur`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event:

```
$('#textbox1_id').blur(function(){
   $('#textbox2_id').val(this.value);
});
```

Comment: Your first example will not work correctly, it will always be a character behind because *keypress* fires before the value is updated.  See http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/09/effectively-detecting-user-input-in-javascript for better input detection.

Comment: @Andy E: Well, I read that, very useful info. Thanks. I updated the answer though, the OP is most likely looking for blur event.

Comment: @patrick, @sarfraz: thanks :-) there's a plug-in to go with it: http://whattheheadsaid.com/projects/input-special-event.

Comment: @Andy E: That's was needed then for sure :)